# Улица "Восьмого марта" или улица "Восьмое марта"?

Tags: грамматика

Улица "Восьмого марта" звучит более правильно, но многие произнося "Восьмое марта", даже на некоторых адресных табличках пишут "8-е марта".

Есть ли правило по этому поводу?

Пруф про таблички (Екатеринбург):[image]

Comment: «…многие произносят "Восьмое марта"...»  Угу. Некоторые и поздравления пишут "с Днём рождениЕМ"

Comment: Как правильно, улица "Ленина" или улица "Ленин"? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я не видел табличек, на которые было бы написано "ул. 8-е марта", тем более чтобы на некоторых - всё-таки даже в самых курьёзных случаях адреса по всей улице выглядят единообразно.

Правильно "Улица восьмого марта", потому что, по российской традиции именования географических объектов, улицы, названные в честь какой-то даты - они именно в честь (кого? чего?) - и именительный падеж там неуместен.

Поэтому [улица Девятого Января](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_9_%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F), поэтому [улица Тысяча Девятьсот Пятого Года](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_1905_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE)) и т.д.

@yellow-sky добавил замечательный комментарий что, бывают и исключения. И тем не менее улицы "Восьмое марта" в русскоязычном мире мне неизвестно.

Comment: Однако, вот пишут, что иногда возможны варианты: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Улица_50_лет_Октября В моём городе тоже была улица с таким названием, и все говорили только «пятьдесят лет», никогда «пятидесяти лет».

Comment: @YellowSky это дельное замечание, там, где форма с числительным написанным цифрами допускает такую двусмысленность то в разговорной речи очень часто всё скатывается к номинативу  - 8 марта тоже относится к этой категории

Comment: Yellow Sky, на самом деле это не исключения - "улица Пятидесятилетия Октября", а не "улица Пятидесятилетие Октября". 
Ну а дальше там - это просто просторечные искажения и сокращения... "У́лица пятьдеся́т лет Октября́" - это, конечно, неправильно и косноязычно и даже где-то бессмысленно. Не памятник Петру I-у, а Петр I-й, угу, самолично :>

Comment: Табличка в Екатеринбурге: https://static.ngs.ru/news/2020/99/preview/4e26185b778d95975d5ef0bef576aa2007177118_585.jpeg

Comment: Cubius, угу : http://ru-prikol.ru/_pu/4/s00787628.jpg     .   
http://ru-prikol.ru/_pu/4/s23311944.jpg

Comment: @Пилум  первое фото только стретьего просмотро дошло. два раза прочел "уничтожение".

Comment: Swift, орёт, наверное, на них - "ты ничтожный таракан !!!", и всякое такое